# Word wrapping in standard texts in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I noticed that some languages, e.g. English and French, have word wrapping in standard texts (Welcome screen, etc.), and some - I suppose, which use Cyrillic - haven't. Is it possible to enable word wrapping for such languages or it is an unrealized function?

Here is example in Bulgarian:
[image]

Update: For the screenshot above I used default script created with wizard. Screen resolution is 2560x1440 and 150% scaling. Here is the code:

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
AppId={{B43BB5B0-E21B-4692-AD97-2E48B7680201}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "bulgarian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Bulgarian.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Dev\Inno Setup 6\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Update 2: version of Inno Setup compiler is 6.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some devil pulled me to check one thing, and it works)
[image]

Just turn off this Windows setting: Settings->Time & language->Language & Region->Administrative language settings->Change system locale->Checkbox "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support". (It's on Win11)

Comment: I've reported it to Inno Setup mailing list: https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/UKYrDl-0a4Y